# Errors cloning git project using Cygwin, msysgit Bash shell works

Tags: git, cygwin

I have Cygwin installed on Windows XP and it comes with git v1.7.3.3.  I also have SSH access to a git repository hosted on a Linux server.  Sometimes, when cloning a large project using Cygwin I get the following error:

```
$ git clone ssh://me@server/git/project
Cloning into project...
remote: Counting objects: 44255, done.
remote: Compressing objects: 100% (8111/8111), done.
fatal: The remote end hung up unexpectedly.61 MiB | 10.91 MiB/s
fatal: early EOF
fatal: index-pack failed
```

This seems to be random - repeating the clone will often work.  However, it is obviously a great cause for concern.

So I installed msysgit instead (which is version 1.7.3.1.msysgit.0) and using the Git Bash shell I do not get this problem.  I'm pretty sure that msysgit is set up to use plink (PuTTY? I'm new to this) which might be relevant.

I wonder if this is something to do with OpenSSH?  I would prefer to use Cygwin as my shell as it has a lot of other packages available that I need to use.

Anyone seen this before or have any ideas how I can fix it?

Comment: You can use msysgit with Cygwin, I would even suggest it over Cygwin's git (which should be somewhat slower because it goes through Cygwin). Just uninstall Git from Cygwin or set an alias for msysgit.

Comment: This did the trick.  Idan, if you turn your comment into an answer I will accept it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

An alias to msysgit does the trick.  I added the following to my Cygwin `.bash_profile`:

```
alias git='"C:/Program Files/git/bin/git.exe"'
```

Hopefully this will be resolved in a future release of the Cygwin git.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I remember this is fixed in recent cygwin 1.7 releases, meanwhile as a workaround try disabling compression:

```
git config --add core.compression -1
```

Comment: Just tried the compression setting but I am still getting the problem.  I also have what Cygwin purports to be the latest release of git.

Comment: This won't happen with http:// protocol either but I don't think thats an option in your case.